Unable to import terraform code because of API failure
Hi i am trying to import devBox defination from the portal using terraform import command when i import it is showing this error

I am using this code from my microsoft using terraform api provider
and terraform import command
terraform import azapi_resource.symbolicname /subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/RGxxx/providers/Microsoft.DevCenter/devcenters/DevCenter/devboxdefinitions/DevBox_Defination
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devcenter/2022-11-11-preview/devcenters/devboxdefinitions?pivots=deployment-language-terraform. Kindly let me know how to fix the issue.

Include osStorageType under properties which is missing in your JSON Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devcenter/2022-11-11-preview/devcenters/devboxdefinitions?pivots=deployment-language-terraform#resource-format-2 @AAdil

As per error message, Terraform expects you to add osStorageType = "" in your code. Check the same value in the PowerShell result and pass it in the Terraform code.
To import the devBox definition using Terraform, you first need to fetch the devBox definition details using the command below and then pass the same values into the Terraform code

Note: Make sure to pass the same values that are displayed in the command output in the Terraform code.

Get-AzDevCenterAdminDevBoxDefinition -ResourceGroupName v-vallepuv-mindtree -DevCenterName venkatdev

Output:


terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
}
resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
  type = "Microsoft.DevCenter/devcenters/devboxdefinitions@2023-04-01"
  name = "samplebox"
  location = "eastus"
  parent_id = "/subscriptions/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.DevCenter/devcenters/venkatdev"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      hibernateSupport = "Enabled"
       imageReference = {
        id = "/subscriptions/yyyyyy/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.DevCenter/devcenters/venkatdev/galleries/default/images/microsoftvisualstudio_visualstudioplustools_vs-2022-ent-general-win11-m365-gen2"
      }
      osStorageType = ""
      sku = {
        capacity = ""
        family = ""
        name = "general_i_8c32gb256ssd_v2"
        size = ""
        tier = ""
      }
    }
  })
}




Output:


Hi @AAdil, Let me know if this helps to resolve the issue?
